# Automorphism of $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2}, \zeta_5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

> Show that if $\sigma \in \mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2}, \zeta_5)/\mathbb Q)$, then $\sigma (\zeta_5) = \zeta^i_5$ for some $i=1,2,3,4$ and $\sigma (\sqrt[5]{2}) = \zeta^j_5 \sqrt[5]{2}$ for some $j=1,2,3,4,5$.

Help please.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

- $(\zeta_5)^4+(\zeta_5)^3+(\zeta_5)^2+(\zeta_5)+1=0$
- $(\sqrt[5]{2})^5-2=0$
- For any $\sigma$, we have $\sigma(a)=a$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Q}$ (by definition, elements of $\mathrm{Aut}(L/K)$ are automorphisms of $L$ that fix $K$).

Comment: since they are both equal to 0, should I set them equal to each other?

Comment: i know i am supposed to get 20 automorphisms

Comment: No, do not set them equal to each other. It should be clear that, whatever it is you need to do, it will involve a $\sigma$ somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- You know that $\zeta_5^5=1$. Therefore
  $$
  1=\sigma(1)=\sigma(\zeta_5^5)=\sigma(\zeta_5)^5,
  $$
  so $\sigma(\zeta_5)$ has to be a fifth root of unity. It cannot be equal to $1$, for $\sigma$ is injective, and $\sigma(1)=1$. Can you see that this leaves the four listed alternatives for $\sigma(\zeta_5)$.
- In the same way $\sigma(\root 5\of 2)$ has to be a fifth root of $2$. Can you see, why this leaves the five listed alternatives for  $\sigma(\root 5\of 2)$.
- To get all 20 automorphisms (that you asked about in a comment to Zev's answer) you need to be able to argue in favor of the following claims:

  1. Why is an automorphism $\sigma$ fully specified, when we know $\sigma(\zeta_5)$ and $\sigma(\root 5\of 2)$?
  2. Why are we free to use all the $4\cdot5=20$ pairs of choices for $\sigma(\zeta_5)$ and $\sigma(\root 5\of 2)$?

The first item in the last bullet is straightforward field theory. For its part the second item is most conveniently handled by referring to suitable theorems of Galois theory, and is perhaps a bit trickier (although standard).

Comment: the second question i am confused by. is it because from my problem $i=1,2,3,4$ and $j=1,2,3,4,5$ so then $4 \times 5$?

Comment: The point there is that even though (more generally) we know that 1) $K=F(a,b)$, 2) $a$ has $m$ conjugates in $K$, and 3) $b$ has $n$ conjugates in $K$, we cannot conclude that $K$ has $mn$ $F$-automorphisms. For example, here we also get the bigger field as $\mathbb{Q}(\root 5\of2,\zeta_5\root 5\of 2)$. This time both generators have 5 conjugates, but yet we won't have $5\cdot5=25$ automorphisms, because we cannot choose the images of the two generators **independently from each other**.

Comment: (cont'd) Proving that there are no obstructions to choosing the images of generators under an automorphism independently from each other can become a bit tricky. Here I would argue as follows (there probably are other equally valid arguments). We know that the bigger field has degree 20 over the rationals, because we get it by joining a root of a quintic and a root of a quartic, and $\gcd(5,4)=1$. We also know that the extension is Galois, because it is the splitting field of a polynomial, and clearly separable. Therefore general theory says that the Galois group has order 20.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint with different approach:**

Note I am using this field extension definition: an extension of a field K is a triple (*i*, K, L), where L is another field, and *i* is a monomorphism of K into L. In other words, K is embedded in L.

This becomes routine with the extension of monomorphisms theorem. I'm leaving out some gritty details. Perhaps you should fill these in.

Let *i* be the inclusion map of $\mathbb Q $ in $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})(\zeta_5)$, that is $i:$ $\mathbb Q $ $\hookrightarrow$ $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})(\zeta_5)$

Then the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[5]{2}$ over $\mathbb Q $ is $x^5 - 2$. So *i*($x^5 - 2$) = $x^5 - 2$ and $x^5 - 2$ has roots $(-1)^{2/5}$$\sqrt[5]{2}$, $-(-1)^{3/5}$$\sqrt[5]{2}$, $(-1)^{4/5}$$\sqrt[5]{2}$ in $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})(\zeta_5)$.

Hence there is a monomorphism *$j_k$* extending *i* such that *$j_k$*: $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})$ $\hookrightarrow$ $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})(\zeta_5)$

Given by:

*$j_k$*: $\sqrt[5]{2}$ $\mapsto$ $\zeta_5^k$$\sqrt[5]{2}$ for k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

The minimal polynomial of $\zeta_5$ over $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})$ is $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$. So *$j_k$*($x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$) = $x^4 + x^3 + x^2 + x + 1$ and has roots $-(-1)^{1/5}$, $(-1)^{2/5}$, $-(-1)^{3/5}$, $(-1)^{4/5}$.

Hence there is a monomorphism (which is actually an automorphism) $\sigma_{k,l}$ extending *$j_k$* such that:
$\sigma_{k,l}$: $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})(\zeta_5)$ $\hookrightarrow$ $\mathbb Q (\sqrt[5]{2})(\zeta_5)$.

Given by:

$\sigma_{k,l}$: $\sqrt[5]{2}$ $\mapsto$ $\zeta_5^k$$\sqrt[5]{2}$ for k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.

$\sigma_{k,l}$: $\zeta_5$ $\mapsto$ $\zeta_5^l$ for l = 1, 2, 3, 4.